# How to retrieve values using XPathNodeIterator

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

I am trying to select values from elements using the XPathNodeIterator. But I am not able to get the expected value from my XML file.

**My XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:Entity xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.mycompany.com/1.0">
    <ns0:Data>
        <Address_Id xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.mycompany.com/1.0">7</Address_Id>
        <Customer_Id xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.mycompany.com/1.0">67</Customer_Id>
        <CustomerName xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.mycompany.com/1.0">My Customer 1</CustomerName>
    </ns0:Data>
</ns0:Entity>
```

**My methods to get the values**
I have created two methods which both doesn't return the values which I would like to have.

```
private static string GetValue_Attempt1(XPathDocument xPathDocument, string xpathExpression)
{
    var xpathNavigator = xPathDocument.CreateNavigator();
    var xpathNodeIterator = xpathNavigator.Select(xpathExpression);
    xpathNodeIterator.MoveNext();
    return xpathNodeIterator.Current.Value;
}

private static string GetValue_Attempt2(XPathDocument xPathDocument, string xpathExpression)
{
    var xpathNavigator = xPathDocument.CreateNavigator();
    var xpathNodeIterator = xpathNavigator.Select(xpathExpression);
    xpathNodeIterator.MoveNext();
    var nodesNavigator = xpathNodeIterator.Current;
    var nodesText = nodesNavigator.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Text, false);
    nodesText.MoveNext();
    return nodesText.Current.Value;
}
```

**My XPath**

- Get Address_Id

  - XPath: `//Data/Address_Id/text()`
  - Attempt1 returns: `767My Customer 1`. Why are all values concatenated ???
  - Attempt2 returns: `7`. Looks OK
- Get Customer_Id

  - XPath: `//Data/Customer_Id/text()`
  - Attempt1 returns: `767My Customer 1`. Why are all values concatenated ???
  - Attempt2 returns: `7`. Why do I get the Address_Id??

**Questions**
Probably I am using an incorrect XPath. But also I don't understand the results. In order to understand whats going on. I would like to know:

1. **Is there a better way (method) to get the value of the elements?**
2. **What is the XPath string which I need to use?**
3. **Why does method `GetValue_Attempt1` return a concatinated string?**
4. **Why does method `GetValue_Attempt2` return the value of only the first element?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XPath returns no matches as you're not taking the namespaces into account.

Your 'Attempt 1' calls `MoveNext()` once, so `Value` returns all the concatenated text in `Data`, and in 'Attempt 2' you call `MoveNext()` twice which positions you inside the `Address_Id` element.

In addition, `Select`, even it the XPath was valid, doesn't actually move the cursor.

If you wanted to get the value, you'd do something like this - note I'm including the namespace in the XPath and using the result of `SelectSingleNode`:

```
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsm.AddNamespace("ns0", "http://schemas.mycompany.com/1.0");

var value = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//ns0:Data/Address_Id", nsm).Value;
```

However, do you have any reason to be using XPath and `XPathDocument` here?  Using the much more expressive and (more) statically typed LINQ to XML would be far preferable, I'd think:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.mycompany.com/1.0";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var addressId = (int)doc.Descendants(ns + "Data")
    .Elements("Address_Id")
    .Single();

var customerId = (int)doc.Descendants(ns + "Data")
    .Elements("Customer_Id")
    .Single();
```